# Looking for datasets about poverty and its effects (eg education, health)

Tags: data-request, economics, global

I want to analyse the impacts of poverty (absolute poverty) on areas such as education and health. Some of the variables I would like to analyse are: years of schooling, rates of diseases, unemployment rate. I am preferably looking for latest data, at least until 2021. I would prefer several datasets, such as data categorized by continents. However, a country specific dataset would also be fine.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific country? How far back are you willing to look? Are you considering doing comparative analyses or focusing on one case study? Where have you already looked?

Answer (score 0):

### [Poverty and Equity Database](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/theworldbank/poverty-and-equity-database)

The latest poverty and inequality indicators are compiled from officially recognized international sources. Poverty indicators include the poverty headcount ratio, poverty gap, and the number of poor at both international and national poverty lines. Inequality indicators include the Gini index and income or consumption distributions. The database includes national, regional and global estimates.

This database is maintained by the Global Poverty Working Group (GPWG), a team of poverty measurement experts from the Poverty Reduction and Equity Network, the Development Research Group, and the Development Data Group.

This is a dataset hosted by the World Bank. The organization has an open data platform found [here](https://databank.worldbank.org/home.aspx) and they update their information according to the amount of data that is brought in. Explore the World Bank using [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/theworldbank/poverty-and-equity-database) and all of the data sources available through the [World Bank organization page](https://databank.worldbank.org/home.aspx)!